# how do i display json objects in ejs using for each ?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

am trying to display the categories, but can't get the expected output. please help me out

```
-index.ejs file 

<h3><%= data.categoryName %></h3>
<ul>
    <% data.categories.forEach(function(item){ %>
    <li><% item.categoryName %></li>
        <% }); %>
</ul>

-app.js

router.get("/",function(req,res){
  //res.sendFile(path + "index.html");
  res.render("index.ejs", {
        title: 'Express - Node Js',
        name : 'sandhya',
        data : jd 
    });
});


-data.json

{
  "categoryName": "Appetizers & Sides",
  "categories": [
    {
      "categoryID": "294",
      "parentID": "304", 
      "subjectID": "7",
      "categoryName": "Apps and Side Dishes (Laura)",
      "forumCategoryID": "163"
    }
```

}

above is the json data and using for each am iterating the values and am receiving the error as **data.forEach is not a function**

Comment: before res.render can you show what jd is contains ? console.log(jd);

Comment: var jd = require ('./data.json');